# Name conflict between namespace and class

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I have a structure with several namespaces, and in each namespace I have one static class that is sort of a small, little spider in the net of that namespace. Like the head of the department.

Let's take an example of two namespaces, `Foo.Bar.Baz` and `Foo.Bar.Quux`.

I have one file which looks like this:

```
namespace Foo.Bar.Baz
{
  static class Baz
  {
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
      Console.Writeline("Doing something...");
    }
  }
}
```

And then a second file:

```
using Foo.Bar.Baz
namespace Foo.Bar.Quux
{
  static class Quux
  {
    public static void GetToWork()
    {
      Baz.DoSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I get an error in the second file when I try to compile because it thinks that Baz is the namespace and not the class. But since I have the line `using Foo.Bar.Baz` it should be fine to use any class inside that namespace without needing to prefix it with the name of the namespace, right? I can use other stuff from that namespace correctly, but not a class with the same name.

It kinda feels like the compiler secretly adds this line to every file: `using Foo.Bar`.

Also, I cannot just put the static `Baz` class inside the `Foo.Bar` namespace since then I will get errors saying that `Foo.Bar.Baz` is not a namespace (since I have other stuff in that namespace and have files that use that namespace). Then it seems the compiler sees the static class and decides that `Foo.Bar.Baz` is a static class and not a namespace.

Of course, I could just rename the static classes to something like Manager but then I would still have to spell out the full `Baz.Manager.SomeMethod` and `Quux.Manager.SomeMethod` in files that need to access stuff from both namespaces. This feels rather clumpsy, I'd rather just have it be `Baz.SomeMethod` and `Quuz.SomeMethod`.

Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is not to name classes like namespaces

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx and the subsequent posts in the series.

Comment: (There are duplicate questions, but I don't have time to find them right now.)

Comment: I wish to not use the same name for a class and a namespace but I just can't come up with a good name structure. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Baz` is a static class, it cannot contain instance members. So, `DoSomething()` must be declared as a static method.

Once you have this, you can either do this:

```
using Foo.Bar.Baz;

public void GetToWork()
{
    Baz.Baz.DoSomething();
}
```

or this:

```
using baz = Foo.Bar.Baz.Baz;

public void GetToWork()
{
    baz.DoSomething();
}
```

However, I do agree with the comments in your question that using the same name for the namespace (logical container for a set of classes) and its containing class (encapsulates data and behavior) may result in readability / maintainability issues.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

```
using Baz = Foo.Bar.Baz.Baz;
```